# How to properly subclass (at least) 5 complex NPC's to have multiple instances of later

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode

I'm trying to call instances (a random amount of: between 3-7) of an NPC class I created. I have 5 (planning to make more) of such different NPC classes and they all subclass SKSpriteNode. Rough layout of each class is unfortunately simple: a method defining the SKPhysicsBody of the NPC & a few short methods (1 being public) to help with animating the class when importing it into GameScene (SKScene subclass). I wrote A LOT OF CODE in GameScene and 90% of it has to do with how the NPC's behave with the world. The reason all these things are not written inside their respective NPC classes is A)I'm not so good at programming yet and B)most of the code in GameScene relies on the update method:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
}
```

Things such as each of the NPC's random movement methods are inside the (void)update method, but these methods are written inside GameScene, not in their respective NPC classes. Because of this, I can't call multiple instances of the same NPC class. If I do, whatever amount I need are created but they're linked to that one random movement method thus overlapping each other while moving in sync making it seem as if it's one NPC unit. So the question: can I just copy NPC methods in GameScene and paste them into their respective class's (obviously working out the kinks) and then just pasting an individual update method into each class? This is so they operate individually when called upon in GameScene and not having to rely on GameScene's (void)update method. If there is some advice, methodology or tutorial on how to go about such things I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the main update method, and put the update method in your NPC subclasses.

Heres a loose example of how you keep track of time outside of your GameScene

```
class NPC: SKSpriteNode {
    var delta = NSTimeInterval(0)


    // this update gets called from the GameScene class, 
    // put all the NPC movement logic in here
    func update(delta: NSTimeInterval){
        self.delta = delta
    }

}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    // time values
    var delta:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(0)
    var last_update_time:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(0)

    let NPCs: [NPC] = [NPC(), NPC(), NPC()]

    func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval){

        if self.last_update_time == 0.0 || catchUp {
            self.delta = 0
        } else {
            self.delta = currentTime - self.last_update_time
        }

        self.last_update_time = currentTime

        for npc in self.NPCs {
            npc.update(delta)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT, THE SAME CODE IN OBJ C**

```
@interface NPC : SKSpriteNode
    -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta;
@end

@implementation NPC
NSTimeInterval _delta;

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta {
    _delta = delta;
}
@end


#import "GameScene.h"
#import "NPC.h"

@implementation GameScene
// time values
NSTimeInterval _delta;
NSTimeInterval _last_update_time;
NSMutableArray *_NPCs;

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    _NPCs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        NPC *npc = [[NPC alloc]init];

        [_NPCs addObject:npc];
    }

}


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (_last_update_time) {
        _delta = currentTime - _last_update_time;
    } else {
        _delta = 0;
    }
    _last_update_time = currentTime;

    for(NPC *npc in _NPCs){
        [npc update:_delta];
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Alleluia! But could you please write this in Objective-C? I'm still Swift illiterate from not learning it yet.

Comment: sorry let me rewrite it

Comment: I forgot to ask what do I do with the NSTimeInterval _delta; inside the NPC class? I see it being used in NPC's update class: _delta = delta; but I'm not sure how to write a proper method into the NPC's update method. How would I write a [self randomMovement]; inside the NPC's update method?